# json extra is null on other intent

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I'm trying to put an extra when calling my intent for the second activity (after logging in) which contains the json data. The json data gets called correctly in the BackgroundTask class in the LoginActivity (I know that, because the Log I put in there with the json string is displayed), but when I do the startChildActivityIntent.putExtra it says that the json_string variable is null (which causes an error in TaskActivity).I hope someone can tell me what's going wrong? I left some comments where things go wrong exactly. Here is the code:

LoginActivity:

```
package com.example.myApp;

some imports

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    SignInButton signInButton;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 6;
    String json_string;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    updateUI(account);
    }

    private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        if(account == null){
            signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

            signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    signIn();
                }
            });

            signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {

            //here the json_string is correct
            new BackgroundTask().execute();

            Context context = LoginActivity.this;

            Class destinationActivity = TaskActivity.class;

            Intent startChildActivityIntent = new Intent(context, destinationActivity);

            //here the json_string is null again

            startChildActivityIntent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);

            startActivity(startChildActivityIntent);
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            String idToken = account.getIdToken();

            updateUI(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            updateUI(null);
        }
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String json_url;
        String JSON_STRING;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            json_url = "https://my_url/json_get_data.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            json_string = result;
            //this log is displayed with the json_string filled in correctly
            Log.i("onpostexecute","json: " + json_string);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

TaskActivity:

```
package com.example.myApp;

some imports

public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_DATA = "https://my_url/json_get_data.php";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter scorpioAdapter;
    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    String json_string;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();
   }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
                        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
                        int count = 0;
                        int id;
                        String name, and, some, other, fields;

                        while (count < jsonObject.length()){
                            JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                            id = o.getInt("id");
                            name = o.getString("name");
                            and= o.getString("and");
                            some= o.getInt("some");
                            other= o.getString("other");
                            fields= o.getString("fields");
                            ListItem item = new ListItem(id, name, and, some, other, fields);

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }

                        myAdapter = new myAdapter (listItems, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        );

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling the background task and without waiting for the result you are passing `json_string` as an extra. As a result `json_string` will be null because the background task has not completed execution.
To avoid this, try calling `TaskActivity` from `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        json_string = result;
        //this log is displayed with the json_string filled in correctly
        Log.i("onpostexecute","json: " + json_string);

         Intent startChildActivityIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
         startChildActivityIntent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);
         startActivity(startChildActivityIntent);
    }
```

and remove the already existing **intent call**

Comment: Ok. I'll do that. Thanks for the help.